Fullscreen option for preview tab with Azure Devops Extension
I am developing an azure devops extension to preview files that don't support the preview functionality. I have everything working but now I am looking to add a fullscreen option exactly like the fullscreen button used for the other tabs (content, history, compare, blame, etc). I'm fairly confused why it doesnt exist already and its used for all tab EXCEPT preview, but regardless Im hoping there is a simple solution as its already a supported functionality.
I am using typescript with the azure-devops-extension-sdk and azure-devops-extension-api.
Edit:
This doesn't appear to be possible currently with azure devops extension SDK creating an iframe for our html file and providing no functions to interact with it/add properties to it, other than resize. So we are unable to allow fullscreen on the iframe and unfortunately resize doesn't give us the ability to move the iframe to take up the entire window.
I created 2 feature requests so feel free to have a look:
Provide more functions to interact with parent iframe: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-Devops-Extension-SDK-edit-properti/10681242
Add fullscreen to preview tab: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Fullscreen-button-on-the-preview-tab/10681246

You can use Fullscreen API. This API allows you to toggle an element between regular and fullscreen modes. Here is an example of how to use the Fullscreen API to toggle the iframe:
function toggleFullscreen() {
if (iframe.requestFullscreen) {
iframe.requestFullscreen();
} else if (iframe.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
iframe.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Safari
} else if (iframe.msRequestFullscreen) {
iframe.msRequestFullscreen(); // IE/Edge
}

See Fullscreen Option Preview Tab in Azure Devops Extension: A Workaround for the detailed info.

This WOULD work my issue is that the azure devops extension creates an iframe by default and it doesnt allow fullscreen. I got it to work by inspecting the page and manually adding allowfullscreen="true" but have not found a way to allow fullscreen from the parent iframe otherwise

Hi @ShockingRotom, it appears that the function you need does not exist currently. You can request a feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better.

@MiaoTian-MSFT Darn.... That's what I figured after not finding anything after a day of testing and researching but was hoping a SO wizard could swoop in and save the day. Thank you!

Thanks for update the question with the feature request tickets. This can make the azure DevOps extension better. Happy coding!
